# Using html2Pdf to export PDF in Angular

Tags: angular, html2pdf

I'm exporting a table to PDF in Angular, using Html2Pdf library, but the exported table does not match with the table when I visualize it (the columns are overlapping).

How can I fix it?[image]

```
  export() {
    var element = document.getElementById('table');
    var opt = {
      margin:[10, 0, 10, 0],
      filename:     'myfile.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg'},
      html2canvas:  { },
      jsPDF:        {orientation: 'landscape' }
    };

    html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

  }
```

Comment: Have you check your `print css` ?